# VBA: No update from the formula

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I am new to VBA and have come up with some code to size a rectangle from two cell values. It seems to work but the problem is it will not update from a formula.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("BJ6"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Shapes("Rectangle 1").Width = Target.Value
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("Bk6"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height = Target.Value
    End If
    End Sub
```

How can I update the rectangle size from a formula?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a worksheet Calculate event macro rather than a worksheet Change event macro.  See:

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx